# How can I get instance of thread with function argument?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0

How can I Start a Thread with a function in powershell.I don't want to Start-job method. I just need .Net thread. 
I have tried this code:

```
function test-function
{
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("yes")
}
$newthread = New-Object System.Threading.Thread(test-function)

$newthread.Start()
```

thanks .

Comment: RunSpaces or jobs are the supported methods for concurrency in PowerShell.

Comment: See [Beginning Use of PowerShell Runspaces](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/26/beginning-use-of-powershell-runspaces-part-1/)

Comment: Here is a module which will run a script asynchronously using jobs:
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Start-Multithread/1.4

Comment: Here is a module which will run a script asynchronously using RunSpaces (a thread with the needed PowerShell Environment)  https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSParallel/2.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get clipboard you can use API like :

```
$getclipboardtext=""
$hwndSelect = $API::GetForegroundWindow()
$openclipboard =  $API::OpenClipboard($hwndSelect); 
[System.IntPtr]$ClipboardDataPointer = $API::GetClipboardData(13);        
if($ClipboardDataPointer -ne $null)
{
[System.IntPtr]$Length = $API::GlobalSize($ClipboardDataPointer);
[System.IntPtr]$gLock = $API::GlobalLock($ClipboardDataPointer);
$Lengthint = [int]$Length
[byte[]] $Buffer = New-Object byte[] $Lengthint;
                [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::Copy($gLock,$Buffer, 0, $Lengthint);
$closeclipboard = $API::CloseClipboard();
$getclipboardtext =[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($Buffer);
}
```

and u can call APIs lie this :

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition 'public class API{
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CloseClipboard()};
```

Comment: tnx for your answer .

Answer (score 1):

You can have a RunSpace approach in this case:

Use the below script written by Ryan Witschger..

All the comments are there with clear explanation on how to use it.

```
#    This is a quick and open-ended script multi-threader searcher
#    
#.Description
#    This script will allow any general, external script to be multithreaded by providing a single
#    argument to that script and opening it in a seperate thread.  It works as a filter in the 
#    pipeline, or as a standalone script.  It will read the argument either from the pipeline
#    or from a filename provided.  It will send the results of the child script down the pipeline,
#    so it is best to use a script that returns some sort of object.
#
#    Authored by Ryan Witschger - http://www.Get-Blog.com
#    
#.PARAMETER Command
#    This is where you provide the PowerShell Cmdlet / Script file that you want to multithread.  
#    You can also choose a built in cmdlet.  Keep in mind that your script.  This script is read into 
#    a scriptblock, so any unforeseen errors are likely caused by the conversion to a script block.
#    
#.PARAMETER ObjectList
#    The objectlist represents the arguments that are provided to the child script.  This is an open ended
#    argument and can take a single object from the pipeline, an array, a collection, or a file name.  The 
#    multithreading script does it's best to find out which you have provided and handle it as such.  
#    If you would like to provide a file, then the file is read with one object on each line and will 
#    be provided as is to the script you are running as a string.  If this is not desired, then use an array.
#    
#.PARAMETER InputParam
#    This allows you to specify the parameter for which your input objects are to be evaluated.  As an example, 
#    if you were to provide a computer name to the Get-Process cmdlet as just an argument, it would attempt to 
#    find all processes where the name was the provided computername and fail.  You need to specify that the 
#    parameter that you are providing is the "ComputerName".
#
#.PARAMETER AddParam
#    This allows you to specify additional parameters to the running command.  For instance, if you are trying
#    to find the status of the "BITS" service on all servers in your list, you will need to specify the "Name"
#    parameter.  This command takes a hash pair formatted as follows:  
#
#    @{"ParameterName" = "Value"}
#    @{"ParameterName" = "Value" ; "ParameterTwo" = "Value2"}
#
#.PARAMETER AddSwitch
#    This allows you to add additional switches to the command you are running.  For instance, you may want 
#    to include "RequiredServices" to the "Get-Service" cmdlet.  This parameter will take a single string, or 
#    an aray of strings as follows:
#
#    "RequiredServices"
#    @("RequiredServices", "DependentServices")
#
#.PARAMETER MaxThreads
#    This is the maximum number of threads to run at any given time.  If resources are too congested try lowering
#    this number.  The default value is 20.
#    
#.PARAMETER SleepTimer
#    This is the time between cycles of the child process detection cycle.  The default value is 200ms.  If CPU 
#    utilization is high then you can consider increasing this delay.  If the child script takes a long time to
#    run, then you might increase this value to around 1000 (or 1 second in the detection cycle).
#
#    
#.EXAMPLE
#    Both of these will execute the script named ServerInfo.ps1 and provide each of the server names in AllServers.txt
#    while providing the results to the screen.  The results will be the output of the child script.
#    
#    gc AllServers.txt | .\Run-CommandMultiThreaded.ps1 -Command .\ServerInfo.ps1
#    .\Run-CommandMultiThreaded.ps1 -Command .\ServerInfo.ps1 -ObjectList (gc .\AllServers.txt)
#
#.EXAMPLE
#    The following demonstrates the use of the AddParam statement
#    
#    $ObjectList | .\Run-CommandMultiThreaded.ps1 -Command "Get-Service" -InputParam ComputerName -AddParam @{"Name" = "BITS"}
#    
#.EXAMPLE
#    The following demonstrates the use of the AddSwitch statement
#    
#    $ObjectList | .\Run-CommandMultiThreaded.ps1 -Command "Get-Service" -AddSwitch @("RequiredServices", "DependentServices")
#
#.EXAMPLE
#    The following demonstrates the use of the script in the pipeline
#    
#    $ObjectList | .\Run-CommandMultiThreaded.ps1 -Command "Get-Service" -InputParam ComputerName -AddParam @{"Name" = "BITS"} | Select Status, MachineName
#


Param($Command = $(Read-Host "Enter the script file"), 
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]$ObjectList,
    $InputParam = $Null,
    $MaxThreads = 20,
    $SleepTimer = 200,
    $MaxResultTime = 120,
    [HashTable]$AddParam = @{},
    [Array]$AddSwitch = @()
)

Begin{
    $ISS = [system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault()
    $RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $MaxThreads, $ISS, $Host)
    $RunspacePool.Open()

    If ($(Get-Command | Select-Object Name) -match $Command){
        $Code = $Null
    }Else{
        $OFS = "`r`n"
        $Code = [ScriptBlock]::Create($(Get-Content $Command))
        Remove-Variable OFS
    }
    $Jobs = @()
}

Process{
    Write-Progress -Activity "Preloading threads" -Status "Starting Job $($jobs.count)"
    ForEach ($Object in $ObjectList){
        If ($Code -eq $Null){
            $PowershellThread = [powershell]::Create().AddCommand($Command)
        }Else{
            $PowershellThread = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($Code)
        }
        If ($InputParam -ne $Null){
            $PowershellThread.AddParameter($InputParam, $Object.ToString()) | out-null
        }Else{
            $PowershellThread.AddArgument($Object.ToString()) | out-null
        }
        ForEach($Key in $AddParam.Keys){
            $PowershellThread.AddParameter($Key, $AddParam.$key) | out-null
        }
        ForEach($Switch in $AddSwitch){
            $Switch
            $PowershellThread.AddParameter($Switch) | out-null
        }
        $PowershellThread.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
        $Handle = $PowershellThread.BeginInvoke()
        $Job = "" | Select-Object Handle, Thread, object
        $Job.Handle = $Handle
        $Job.Thread = $PowershellThread
        $Job.Object = $Object.ToString()
        $Jobs += $Job
    }

}

End{
    $ResultTimer = Get-Date
    While (@($Jobs | Where-Object {$_.Handle -ne $Null}).count -gt 0)  {

        $Remaining = "$($($Jobs | Where-Object {$_.Handle.IsCompleted -eq $False}).object)"
        If ($Remaining.Length -gt 60){
            $Remaining = $Remaining.Substring(0,60) + "..."
        }
        Write-Progress `
            -Activity "Waiting for Jobs - $($MaxThreads - $($RunspacePool.GetAvailableRunspaces())) of $MaxThreads threads running" `
            -PercentComplete (($Jobs.count - $($($Jobs | Where-Object {$_.Handle.IsCompleted -eq $False}).count)) / $Jobs.Count * 100) `
            -Status "$(@($($Jobs | Where-Object {$_.Handle.IsCompleted -eq $False})).count) remaining - $remaining" 

        ForEach ($Job in $($Jobs | Where-Object {$_.Handle.IsCompleted -eq $True})){
            $Job.Thread.EndInvoke($Job.Handle)
            $Job.Thread.Dispose()
            $Job.Thread = $Null
            $Job.Handle = $Null
            $ResultTimer = Get-Date
        }
        If (($(Get-Date) - $ResultTimer).totalseconds -gt $MaxResultTime){
            Write-Error "Child script appears to be frozen, try increasing MaxResultTime"
            Exit
        }
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $SleepTimer

    } 
    $RunspacePool.Close() | Out-Null
    $RunspacePool.Dispose() | Out-Null
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer but  have this script any Likeness with my script ? i just need to fix my syntax and my code . i dont need alternative

Comment: Give me sometime...I will go through it. I am presently from mobile. Although i am going through it. I will create a dummy function and with that i will use the multi-threading and will post it.

Comment: @saftargholi If you care only for syntax, then you can use this `New-Object System.Threading.Thread ([System.Threading.ThreadStart]${function:test-function})`, but, please, do not try to start that thread.

Comment: As @PetSerAl said, don't try to start a thread created this way.  You need to use a RunSpace.  If you search online you can find several examples.

Comment: @PetSerAl hi man thank you for your answer . you right thread cant start . i want to start thread in powershell because i need to set [System.Threading.ApartmentState]::STA in my thread . i look in internet about start thread i see the start-job method but this method have any parameter that alternative of STA thread . can you help me  ?

Comment: Start-job have file -FilePath parameter. which can trigger multiple scripts as separate threads. It can trigger multiple functions also. But it seems that you dont want to use the native cmdlets. SO in Dot net also you can work on it. Go through the link [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/150777)  If this what you meant @saftargholi

Comment: @RanadipDutta does start-job have alternative of [System.Threading.ApartmentState]::STA ? i want to get clipboard from started job .

Comment: Are you referring to state `ApartmentState aps = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState();`

Comment: @saftargholi You need to use `Runspace.ApartmentState` property: `$r=[RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace(); $r.ApartmentState='STA'; $r.Open()`.

Comment: @RanadipDutta can u give me your answer in the answer section ? my english not good .

Comment: Sure Sure. Give me sometime on it.

Comment: @PetSerAl how i can pass script block to it to Execute ?

Comment: @PetSerAl : A script block is defined as `$a={"My name is Ranadip"}; $a.gettype(); ` . Get type will give you the type of the block. :)

Answer (score 0):

PetSer Used a Thread Method which is exactly and alternative for for the Thread Start.

```
$r=[RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace(); $r.ApartmentState='STA';
$r.Open()
```

And for getting the state you can use :

```
ApartmentState aps = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState();
```

Comment: how i can pass script block to it to execute ?

Comment: please write full answer .

Answer (score 0):

you can use `start-job` method like :

start-job -scriptblock {you're script , function , method or ... here }